# Append to generic array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, generics

I have a protocol named `Foo` and a struct named `Bar`. `Bar` conforms to `Foo`.

```
protocol Foo {}    
struct Bar: Foo {}
```

Appending a `Bar` instance to an array of `Bar` works as expected.

```
var array = [Bar]()
array.append(Bar())
```

Now, I have a generic struct called `Baz` that's initialized with a type that conforms to `Foo` (e.g. `Bar`).

```
struct Baz<T: Foo> {
    private(set) var array = [T]()

    init() {
        if T.self is Bar.Type {
            // Error: Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type (Bar)
            array.append(Bar())
        }
    }
}
```

Attempting to append to the array results in the following error:

> Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type (Bar)

Why doesn't this work as expected?

As an aside, the use case is something like this:

```
let bazBarStack = Baz<Bar>().array
let bazQuxStack = Baz<Qux>().array
```

Comment: may be something like `array.append(Bar() as T)`?

Comment: Yes, casting to T fixed it. Somehow that solution totally alluded me haha. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store objects in array, that are of type T. Therefore you should cast using `as! T`:

```
struct Baz<T: Foo> {
    private(set) var array = [T]()

    init() {
        if T.self is Bar.Type {
            array.append(Bar() as! T)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've offered the same solution as @njzk2 (in the comments). But, you did elaborate with the example, so I suppose it's ok to mark this as correct... it does need to be forcibly cast, so thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Because `array` holds elements of a single type `T`, which must conform to `Foo` but is not necessarily compatible with `Bar`. It looks like you wish to have an array that can hold anything conforming to `Foo`; in this case, get rid of the generics altogether and simply write

```
private(set) var array = [Foo]()
```

and then your init will be

```
init() {
    array.append(Bar())
}
```